# What is indirectly recursive?

Tags: java, recursion

I have this problem on my homework and I don't understand it.

Assume there are four methods A, B, C, and D. 
Method A calls method B, and method B calls method A.
Method C calls method D, and method D calls method A.
Which of the following methods is indirectly recursive?

What is indirectly recursive and what isn't?

Comment: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~tamaras/recursion/Direct_vs_Indirect.html

Comment: Take the definition of directly recursive - a method calling itself - then apply that to an indirect approach - a method that calls another method which calls the original calling method.

Comment: Well then it would be B and A because they are the only ones that return to their original.

Comment: Draw a directed graph of who calls whom, and look for cycles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A -> B -> A <- D <- C
```

`Indirectly Recursive` : Method A and B, as they indirectly call themselves by calling each other.

`Directly Recursive` : None of them as no method calls itself.

See this [link](http://www.introprogramming.info/tag/direct-and-indirect-recursion/) for detailed information.

Comment: I think you may have missed it but it's A and B. You were correct in that A is indirect because it calls B who calls A again. B does the same thing.

Comment: You're right ! I guess it all depends on how deeply you look at things :) Edited the answer accordingly.